# Facing issues trying to Parse JSON in Lua

Tags: lua, json, corona-sdk

**Problem statement:**

Need help trying to load a JSON file into a table array in Lua for Corona SDK development.

**My Objective:**

Call specific data from JSON file to my application by using key value pairs.

**Current Behavior of application**

Corona simulator console just return a table ID like --> table: 114AF7D8

**Expected Behavior**

Returns the name "Smith" when i print(DialogsTable.name[2])

A reference to the Lua code:

```
local json = require( "json" )

local DialoguesTable = {}

local path = system.pathForFile("simple.json", system.DocumentsDirectory ) 

function putJsonDataInTable(filename, base)
    local base = base or system.DocumentsDirectory
    local path = system.pathForFile(filename, base)
    local fh = io.open(path,"r")
    if fh then
        local contents = fh:read("*a")
        io.close( fh )
        local DialoguesTable = json.decode(contents)
        return DialoguesTable
    else
        return nil
    end
end 
putJsonDataInTable()  
print(DialoguesTable.name[2])
```

A reference to the JSON file:

```
{  
 "name":["John","Smith"],  
 "age":30  
}
```

Comment: Use `DialoguesTable = putJsonDataInTable()`  instead of `putJsonDataInTable()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff please post that as an answer we can upvote/accept :)